# how to convert a mysql table to text file in php?

Tags: php, mysql, text-files

What is the php script for converting a mysql table to text file? I have converted it to CSV format which opens up as a excel file. I also want the table data in a text file. How do I do it?

For converting it to csv format, I used the header data as:

```
$filename = "export_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
```

I tried using header("Content-type: text/plain"); and used the .txt extension. It didn't work.. Someone guide me please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to save my table in text format, saved as a ms word application with .doc extension. And the headers are given below

```
header("Content-Type: application/msword");
header("Content-disposition: attachment" . date("Y-m-d") . ".doc");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".doc");
```

But now I'm trying to display it in a table format in the text file.. Because it looks like junk data without any alignment. Adding tab space doesn't help..  Any suggestions?

Comment: You answered your own question with a question and then selected that "answer" as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

[`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) will create the file in CSV format for you:

```
mysqldump -u User1 -p -t -T/path/to/sav [database] --fields-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by=\r\n --no-create-db --no-create-info
```

`--fields-enclosed-by=\"` ensures that all of your fields are encapsulated by quotations, and `--fields-terminated-by=,` makes those fields comma-separated.

Answer (score 1):

what about this one - SQL (cvs)

```
SELECT          *  
FROM            TABLE1 
INTO            OUTFILE 'path\file.cvs' 
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\,' 
                OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

If you want plain text -

```
SELECT          *  
FROM            TABLE1 
INTO            OUTFILE 'path\file.sql'
```

[mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

> The SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE
>   'file_name' form of SELECT writes the
>   selected rows to a file. The file is
>   created on the server host, so you
>   must have the FILE privilege to use
>   this syntax. file_name cannot be an
>   existing file, which among other
>   things prevents files such as
>   /etc/passwd and database tables from
>   being destroyed. As of MySQL 5.0.19,
>   the character_set_filesystem system
>   variable controls the interpretation
>   of the file name.

Comment: Do you have write permissions for the destination?

Answer (score 1):

A .csv file *is* a plain text file, you're just sending headers that cause it to be opened in Excel.

If you want the same format file, but not opened in Excel, just *do not* send these headers:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
```

And instead send this one:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

If you want to force the text-file download, try this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
```

Comment: If I do so, the contents are displayed in the browser.. It is not saved as a text file..

Comment: Updated with an example that should force a text file download.